# django Q object nested with reduce

Tags: django

Got very complex query (please do not try to solve example - the problem is more complex)

```
crit=[]
crit.append(Q(firstcond = name) | Q(firstcond__isnull = True)
crit.append(Q(secondcond = name) | Q(firstcond__isnull = True)

MyObject.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, crit))
```

This works as expected:

```
WHERE (firstcond = name OR firstcond IS NULL) AND (secondcond = name OR secondcond IS NULL)
```

But now I need some OR:

```
WHERE ((firstcond = name OR firstcond IS NULL) AND (secondcond = name OR \
secondcond IS NULL)) OR (third = value)
```

I can't add third int crit list, because operator.and_ in reduce. I have to add operator._or after reduce, but HOW?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No need to use `reduce`:

```
crit = (Q(firstcond = name) | Q(firstcond__isnull = True)) & (Q(secondcond = name) | Q(firstcond__isnull = True)) | Q(third = value)
MyObject.objects.filter(crit)
```

If you want `reduce` for some reason:

```
MyObject.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, crit) | Q(third = value))
```

Or:

```
MyObject.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_([reduce(operator.and_, crit), Q(third = value)]))
```

Comment: Please give me one work day to check if it works - but looks delicious!

Comment: Thank you very much - that's what I need